# Select categories in dropdown-menu with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, powerbi

Is it possible to get all the names in the dropdown-menu "MUNICIPIO" in this Power BI [here](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYjQ1NTA2OTYtYTNkMi00ZTM4LWI2ODUtZjE0MTdhODg2OWU3IiwidCI6IjU2YzFlMmZiLTg3YzEtNGRlMC1hNmFjLWQwNTY2YzA4Y2U2NiJ9)?

So far, I managed to click the menu. But only part of the options apper in the htlm code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

cService = webdriver.ChromeService("chromedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = cService)

url = "https://app.powerbi.com/view r=eyJrIjoiYjQ1NTA2OTYtYTNkMi00ZTM4LWI2ODUtZjE0MTdhODg2OWU3IiwidCI6IjU2YzFlMmZiLTg3YzEtNGRlMC1hNmFjLWQwNTY2YzA4Y2U2NiJ9"

driver.get(url)

clickable = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='MUNICIPIO']")
ActionChains(driver).context_click(clickable).perform()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class = 'pbi-menu-item-text-container'").click()
```

My final goal is to loop through the option in the menu once I get their names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution focuses on sending **Keys.DOWN** to the dropdown menu and reading the highlighted element. It's not nice or perfect, but it does the job.

> ```
> driver.get('https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYjQ1NTA2OTYtYTNkMi00ZTM4LWI2ODUtZjE0MTdhODg2OWU3IiwidCI6IjU2YzFlMmZiLTg3YzEtNGRlMC1hNmFjLWQwNTY2YzA4Y2U2NiJ9')
>
> dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@aria-label='MUNICIPIO']")))
> dropdown.click()
>
> curr_elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-row-index=1]')))
> curr_elem.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
>
> elems = []
>
> while len(elems) == 0 or elems[-1] != curr_elem.text:
>   elems.append(curr_elem.text)
>   curr_elem.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
>   time.sleep(0.1)
>   curr_elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="slicerItemContainer setFocusRing"]')))
> ```

The time.sleep() is required, because otherwise Selenium occasionally reads the text of the element faster than the website reacts to the down key.